# Odd Result with a dictionary of Dictionaries, why?

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

I have need in a module for a dictionary of dictionaries but for some reason it is not producing the results That I was expecting.  I have made up an example that illustrates the problem , shown below.

```
 Dim mydict As New Dictionary(Of Int32, Dictionary(Of Int32, Decimal))
    Dim outerkey As Integer = 2
    Dim innerkey As Integer = 7
    Dim innerDictionary As Dictionary(Of Int32, Decimal) = Nothing
    Dim innerkeyvalue As Decimal = CDec(12.3)


    If Not mydict.TryGetValue(outerkey, innerDictionary) Then
        '       ' So we need to create one
        innerDictionary = New Dictionary(Of Int32, Decimal)
        mydict.Add(outerkey, innerDictionary)
    End If
    If Not innerDictionary.TryGetValue(innerkey, innerkeyvalue) Then
        ' So we need to create it
        innerDictionary.Add(innerkey, innerkeyvalue)
    Else
        Dim retrievedvalue As Decimal = innerDictionary.Item(innerkey)
        innerkeyvalue += retrievedvalue
        innerDictionary.Add(innerkey, innerkeyvalue)
    End If
```

If I place a breakpoint on the 'If Not innerDictionary.TryGetValue(innerkey, innerkeyvalue) Then
' line the value of innerkey is 7 and the value of innerkeyvalue is 12.3, which is exactly as I would expect.  Those values aren't yet in the inner dictionary so I would then expect the code to go to the next line (which it does) to add those values to the inner dictionary.

What happens though is that the value of the innerkey remains as it should (7) but the value of innervalue changes from 12.3 to 0.

I'm obviously doing something stupid, or I have failed to understandstand a fundamental principle of dictionaries within dictionaries.  Either way I'd be grateful if someone could explain why I'm seeing what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) doc

> if the key is not found, then the value parameter gets the appropriate default value for the type TValue; **for example, 0 (zero) for integer types**, false for Boolean types, and null for reference types.

default value for decimal is 0

you would need another variable for the second parameter of the `trygetvalue`